# Change mui5 theme back to the default (purple) v4 theme

Tags: material-ui

After upgrading to mui5 my theme has changed from purple as the primary colour to blue. I never set this anywhere in my code, I was just relying on defaults.

Is there an easy way to get this theme back in v5 without having to set up all the colours manually?

Comment: If you can put your relevant code here, and maybe create a codesandbox with the bug, you'll get help a lot quicker.